# Update column of html table on ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i am creating a renaming application for cloud
i am creating HTML table with two fields name and new name my code is

```
 $(document).on("click","#childern li",function(){

            var subFolderID = $(this).attr( "id" );

            var objlst=    $(this);
            var request;
            request = $.ajax({
                context:this,
                url: url,
                method: "POST",

                data: {'id': subFolderID},
                ContentType: 'application/json'
            });
            request.done(function( response ) {

                var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

                var trHTML="";
                for(var i = 0, l = result.length; i < l; i++){
                    trHTML += '<tr><td class="col-md-2">' + result[i].name +
                        '</td><td class="newName">' + result[i].name +
                        '</td></tr>';

                }


                $('#records_table').append(trHTML);

            });
            request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            });
        });
```

My code to apyly rules for remove text working fine i neeed to show a preview for user i am getting ajax response fine result was ok but i cant understand how i update my table column with new name to show good preview

```
 $(".btnClick").click(function(e) {
        var url ='<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/drive/preview';
        e.preventDefault();
        var objlst=    $(this);
        var removeText = $("#removeText").val();
        var mydata = [];
       var i = 0;
        $('#records_table .newName').each(function()
        {
            mydata[i++] =($(this).html());

        });

        var request;
        request = $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "POST",
            data: {'rtext': removeText , 'tableData' : mydata},
            ContentType: 'application/json'
        });
        request.done(function( response ) {


            var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

            var trHTML="";
            for(var i = 0, l = result.length; i < l; i++){

            }


            $('#records_table ').(trHTML);


        });
```

here is my controller code

```
public function getPreviewData()
{

    $this->load->library('STOneDrive');

    if (!$this->stonedrive->is_Connected) {
        $refreshToken = "";
        $this->stonedrive->Reconnect($refreshToken);
    }
    $result = array();
    $contents = [];
$a = ($this->input->post('rtext'));
$b = ($this->input->post('tableData'));

    for($i=1;$i<count($b);$i++)
    {
        $content  = str_replace($a,"",$b);
    }


    echo json_encode($content);

}
```

in ajax response i am getting result fine problem is how i update my html table with result.

Comment: Please show the structure of the data returned by the "preview" ajax call. Either you can return enough data to re-draw the whole table, or you probably need to draw the initial one with some IDs/classes on the `<td>`s you want to replace later, so you know where to re-use them.